# nice to see you vs good to see you

Tags: usage

While I am walking on the street, the college, shopping ...etc I meet native American friends. When we finish a quick chat, I used to say nice to see you. They say good to see you. Is there any difference in usage between "nice to see you" and "good to see you"? Am I wrong if I say nice to see you.

Comment: By "Native American" do you mean the aboriginal people of America, sometimes called "American Indians"

Comment: @MikeHarris Please don't answer questions in comments. Make that an proper answer so it can be voted on by the community

Comment: Men, women or both? "nice" probably ends up on the feminine side of usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both mean the same thing and can be used interchangeably.

Comment: That's right but "talking the talk" is essential for acceptance in peer groups.

Comment: @WeatherVane If I said "nice to see you" to someone, I wouldn't even notice a difference whether someone replied "good to see you" or "nice to see you." Although I think it would be more colloquial to add "too" to the end (e.g., "nice to see you, too") when replying.

Comment: Good for you but many people are picky when judging the language others speak.